# Renaming root folder in Three.JS project causes weird aliasing bug

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, three.js

I hate to be the guy who makes a stackoverflow account just to ask a question (I owe a lot to stackoverflow), but this really has me utterly stumped.

For months I've been plagued with a mysterious bug that causes a bizarre rendering error in my three.js VR projects when running on Android. 
I've always been able to solve it by basically rebuilding everything from scratch virtually line-by-line to see what causes the problem. I've never had any luck pinpointing the cause however.

[image: Here's a side-by-side image of the problem (left is normal, right is an identical scene that's having the problem)]

Today, I found a way to reproduce the problem - I took google's Google Cardboard three.js example (which you can find at vr.chromeexperiments.com (I'm not allowed more than two links until I get my 10 reputation)), added in some spheres (so that there was something to watch for in regards to the aliasing) and found that it was running fine.

[image: Here's the original folder structure.]

Renaming the root folder from 'WTF' (can you tell this is frustrating me? :P)to 'WTFF' will result in the rendering error appearing. Copying the folder, renaming the original 'WTFF' and naming the copy 'WTF' will result in the original displaying the rendering error, and the copy displaying correctly. That is, the error is caused by the project's root folder not having the name it had when the project was first created. I'm editing everything in notepad++.

Am I missing something here? The only files here are plaintext .js and .html, and a few images. Why does the root folder's name have any influence at all on how WebGL content is rendered? Is there some way around this error? Does anybody know what's causing it? I'm pretty familiar with three.js, but I've never done anything directly in WebGL, so there might be something under the hood that I'm not aware of perhaps that involves the folder structure?

I didn't include any code since the problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with the actual code within the file (this problem has cropped up in every three.js project I've worked on). But let me know if you think it might help.

Thanks so much in advance! :)

---

Update: I went away for half an hour and came back - now the original WTF-named folder structure is also displaying the error. I'm forcing a reload with `window.location.reload(true);`, so I have absolutely no idea what is going on anymore.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I may have found the solution:

While I'm not sure of the exact underlying causes, it seems the problem lies within Chrome for Android, and not within WebGL or Three.js. 
It seems that Chrome for Android is caching the WebGL content and doing something with it that causes this error to crop up if the folder structure changes.

The problem can be fixed by clearing the Chrome cache (Settings -> Application Manager -> Chrome -> Clear Cache).

I hope this helps anyone who encounters this problem in the future!